# Python - "NameError: name 'c_bool' is not defined"

Tags: python

I am trying to use the python library mosquitto for writing a program for maemo.  I am using the package libmosquitto, which provides a mosquitto.py library file (http://mosquitto.org/documentation/python/).

The program import mosquitto using the following line of code:

```
import mosquitto
```

The program runs fine on my desktop, but failed on the device with the following error:

```
NameError: name 'c_bool' is not defined
```

I am using python2.5 on the device.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c_bool` isn't defined in python 2.5. It's new in 2.6:

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_bool

Possibly you could get away with adding

```
c_bool = c_int
```

after the line that reads

```
from ctypes import *
```

in `mosquitto.py`. Seems sketchy though...

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I tried subscribing to a MQTT server, and it worked as expected.

Thanks for the help!